# Error connecting to migrated RDS (from another aws account) from ec2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, database-migration

So we have two AWS accounts - one for stage and other for production. Now in stage, there is ec2 in public subnet and rds in private subnet. Ec2 and rds are connected to each other. Data is also populated in stage environment's rds.
Now we have migrated this ec2 and Rds to production aws account.

So the steps I followed for rds migration :
Created rds snapshot in stage -> copy snapshot -> share snapshot with production.
Opened production account -> copied shared snapshot -> Restore snapshot.

But now when trying to connect to this new migrated rds from production ec2 via Mysql workbench, it is giving error "Failed to connect to Mysql at xxxx...:3306 with user xxxx. Host *private_ip_of_ec2* id not allowed to connect to this mysql server"

Stange thing, I tried crreating a new rds in production aws account, and it can be easily connected from ec2. Only the migrated rds from stage aws account does not connect.

Can somebody help in this issue ?

Note :

1. rds master username and password are same in both stage and production accounts.
2. ec2 was in public subnet in stage, but in production it is in private subnet.

Comment: have you mapped the new endpoint of RDS to the server in EC2 correctly 
and also check the DB Subnet group also